# Getting name of extracted file after unzipping

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, 7zip

I'm trying to assign the name of the file that is extracted from the zip as a string that I can pass around.

The following is my code so far:

```
cl = '7z x -ppassowrd Week45_10.zip'
args = shlex.split(cl)
p = subprocess.call(args)
file = open('VENDATA_10', 'r')
```

VENDATA_10 is the name of the file that is extracted, however, the name of the file extracted from the zip will vary. How do I find the name of the extracted file so that I can open whatever that file is called instead of VENDATA_10?

Comment: Do you know any other information, like where the file will be extracted to or what the contents of the archive are?

Comment: For now, the file will be extracted in my home directory (/home/user/); The zipfile extract will be one or more text files.

Comment: The `ZipFile` module should be able to read the file directory even if it couldn't uncompress (i.e., if a 7z-specific compression is used).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could capture the output from the process. 7z will print the filenames that it extracts to the standard output. The output might look like this:

```
7-Zip 4.44 beta  Copyright (c) 1999-2007 Igor Pavlov  2007-01-20
p7zip Version 4.44 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,2 CPUs)

Processing archive: Week45_10.zip

Extracting  VENDATA_10

Everything is Ok
```

So you want to capture the lines that start with "Extracting  ". To capture the output you'll need to pipe the output from the process into you program and read it. You can used `communicate()` from `subprocess` to get the full output.

I've extended you code a bit to do this:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import shlex

cl = '7z x -ppassowrd Week45_10.zip'
args = shlex.split(cl)
p = Popen(args, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
(stdoutdata, stderrdata) = p.communicate()

START_WITH = "Extracting  "
N = len(START_WITH)
lines = [line.strip() for line in stdoutdata.split('\n')]
files = [line[N:] for line in lines if line.startswith(START_WITH)]

print files
```

You should be aware that there might arise problems if the files already exist, because then `7z` will prompt the user if it should overwrite the files. If you want to handle that then you need to control the input to the `7z` process also. You might want to look at the `pexpect` module for that.